# Facebook Connect Javascript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, facebook

At the top of my page I put this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

Then in the body I do this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

Then I have this later on in the page:

```
<fb:login-button perms="publish_stream">Connect with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

And then in my JQuery document ready I have this:

```
FB.init({
        appId: '115************', cookie: true,
        status: true, xfbml: true
    });
```

In FF, everything loads fine, and when I click Connect with Facebook, everything works fine. In EVERY other browser, everything LOADS fine, but when I click Connect with Facebook, I get this error:

> FB.login() called before calling
>   FB.init().

Any ideas?

P.S. Puttin the `init()` script in the `head` of the document doesn't work either. Gives the same error.

P.P.S. Moving `init()` to the `<head>` makes it work for IE and FF now, but not Safari or Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to consider is that `<div id="fb-root"></div>` should always be the last thing on the page, right before the closing `</body>` tag.

**Updated**:

Also, instead of calling FB.init() in your document.ready, do what [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/) suggests and put it in the `fbAsyncInit` block:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: Moved it for good measure, but still doesn't fix the issue =/